# Is there a Vorto Eclipse Model Importer API

Tags: iot, bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto, bosch-iot

I am setting up an automation, and wanted to ask if there is an API to import Vorto models. Right now, it looks like it is only possible via the website (https://vorto.eclipse.org/#/import).

At https://www.eclipse.org/vorto/swagger/ there is a 'Vorto Importer Plugin API'. I guess this API is only for importing plugins as the name suggests.

If this is not available, are there any plans to implement such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently the Repository API of Vorto 0.11 does not support to import models via REST. It is a pure read-only REST API. You can "only" import models via the Repository Web Interface (https://vorto.eclipse.org)

However there is a GitHub issue about your request: https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/issues/1667 and it will be available in 0.12 Release, which is planned for end of august.

The Vorto Importer Plugin API is an API to implement an Importer Plugin that you can register with the Vorto Repository. An Importer plugin could for example be a Web Of Things or JSON Schema Plugin, that converts these 3rd party descriptors to Vorto Information Models. As I understand your question, that is not what you wanna do :)